# Issue loading Twitter Tweets into UITableView w/ AFNetworking 1.2

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, twitter

I am using AFNetworking 1.2 to create an App that displays the tweets from the user. The app already successfully authenticates the user but doesn't display the tweets. Here is what I am doing to receive the Tweets.

```
- (void)fetchTweets
{
    self.twitterClient = [[AFOAuth1Client alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/"] key:@"4oFCF0AjP4PQDUaCh5RQ" secret:@"NxAihESVsdUXSUxtHrml2VBHA0xKofYKmmGS01KaSs"];

    [self.twitterClient authorizeUsingOAuthWithRequestTokenPath:@"/oauth/request_token" userAuthorizationPath:@"/oauth/authorize" callbackURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"floadt://success"] accessTokenPath:@"/oauth/access_token" accessMethod:@"POST" scope:nil success:^(AFOAuth1Token *accessToken, id responseObject) {
        [self.twitterClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [self.twitterClient getPath:@"statuses/user_timeline.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSArray *responseArray = (NSArray *)responseObject;
            tweets = responseArray;
            [responseArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                NSLog(@"Success: %@", obj);
            }];
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

Here is how I am attempting to load the received Tweets into to the UITableView:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TweetCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *tweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *text = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];
    NSString *name = [[tweet objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"];

    cell.textLabel.text = text;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"by %@", name];

    return cell;
}
```

I have added the Cell Identifier in Storyboard already, so that is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Reload table after fetching all tweets and assigning it to array

means

```
- (void)fetchTweets
{
    self.twitterClient = [[AFOAuth1Client alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/"] key:@"4oFCF0AjP4PQDUaCh5RQ" secret:@"NxAihESVsdUXSUxtHrml2VBHA0xKofYKmmGS01KaSs"];

    [self.twitterClient authorizeUsingOAuthWithRequestTokenPath:@"/oauth/request_token" userAuthorizationPath:@"/oauth/authorize" callbackURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"floadt://success"] accessTokenPath:@"/oauth/access_token" accessMethod:@"POST" scope:nil success:^(AFOAuth1Token *accessToken, id responseObject) {
        [self.twitterClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [self.twitterClient getPath:@"statuses/user_timeline.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSArray *responseArray = (NSArray *)responseObject;
            tweets = responseArray;
            [tableView reloadData];
            //^ Add this line
            [responseArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                NSLog(@"Success: %@", obj);
            }];
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

Note : `tableView` is your tableview name

Comment: My tableview is actually called TableView and it is outleted in the .h part of my file does that change it.

Comment: I changed the name of my table to tableView and it still didnt change